# Password-protect private stuff

Tags: content-management-system, archive, password-protection, database

I'm looking for a portable way (application, file format, library/API, CMS, DBMS, whatever) to deny read and write access to a collection of text files unless the user enters the password. This would be for personal use, i.e. the files would be stored on my computer, which I share with other people.

I've already tried with:

- password protected archives: but even a minor edit to one file requires unpacking
  and re-packing everything, which is quite annoying
- a wiki backed by a DBMS, with a single password protected account: but the DBMS
  root user will be able to read my stuff

... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to mount an encrypted volume on my PC.  Also available for Mac and Linux.

I mount the volume when I want to work with the files (the volume shows up as a new drive letter), and unmount it when done.  The mount does not survive a reboot, so shutting down the computer guarantees that the volume will have to be re-mounted before it can be accessed again.

Comment: I just gave a look at "Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software" on en.wikipedia, and found out that TC is the most suited for me among those applications. So thanks for your time. However, at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=data-leaks, it says one should also encrypt the system partition, or run a live OS inside RAM with no unencrypted partitions mounted, which is another of the solutions I tried. This is because the OS can otherwise dump file names and/or data, especially Windows. So I think I'll return to run Linux in RAM mode, or inside a VM, or on a USB stick, or just

Comment: on a separate partition on my computer, with only one passw-protected account - i.e. mine. There, TC will be of no use - after all, there will be no other user than me - so I think I'll run a wiki instead, maybe MediaWiki. I think that disk encrypt. software in general, and TC in particular, are more well suited for transmitting files on an insecure channel, between secure machines, than for working on files on an insecure machine, so I believe it will be a great tool for securing my backups of the DB underlying the wiki. Again, thanx for your time and your idea. -ignis